# reverse sorting a list preserving the order of the same number

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that looks like this

```
lst = ['3.0', '3.0 (key)', '2.0', '2.0 (key)', '1.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.1', '1.1 (key)']
```

i want to reverse sort it so that it should still looks the same order of numbers but item with text `'(key)'` should come first.

```
['3.0 (key)', '3.0', '2.0 (key)', '2.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.0', '1.1 (key)', '1.1']
```

what I have tried so far is doing is

```
lst.sort(reverse=True)
```

that reverses the whole list ignoring the number order
resulting into:

```
['1.1', '1.1 (key)', '1.0 (key)', '1.0', '3.0', '3.0 (key)', '2.0 (key)', '2.0']
```

What I want is

```
['1.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.1', '1.1 (key)', '2.0', '2.0 (key)', '3.0', '3.0 (key)']
```

Comment: Do you want to swap the even indices with the odd indices, or is that just a bad example?

Comment: I have fixed it, what I want is `['3.0 (key)', '3.0', '2.0 (key)', '2.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.0', '1.1 (key)', '1.1']`

Comment: Sorry to say, but for all purposes (numberwise) the 1.1 should come between 2.0 and 1.0 - why do you want to sort all numbers decreasing but sort the _larger_ 1.1 behind the _lower_  1.0 (regardless of if it has (key) or not? How should it behave it a `['2.3 (key)','2.3']` was added to your data?

Comment: Please answer my above question. And could the input be like `['3.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.0', '3.0 (key)'`? If so, what's the desired result?

Comment: (after your last edit the _number order resulting into:`['1.1', '1.1 (key)', '1.0 (key)', '1.0', '3.0', '3.0 (key)', '2.0 (key)', '2.0']`_ is not what the command `lst.sort(reverse=True)` would output. typo?)

Comment: sorry I may have confused you , because I am also confused. the problem is the list gets populated dynamically and I earlier pasted what I tried out of was not from the latest , the anser that is deleted was close except those  group I wanted to be in ascending order

Comment: Ignoring the questions... alright, I guess you don't want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly ,

```
def _first_element(elements):
    return elements[0]
# First you zip the items to groups.
groups = zip(*[iter(self._takes)]*2)
# then sort the groups in reverse
zipped.sort(key=first_element, reverse=True)
then build a new list what 
new_list=[]
for item in zipped:
    new_list.append(item[-1])
    new_list.append(item[0])

> new_list
> ['1.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.1', '1.1 (key)', '2.0', '2.0 (key)', '3.0', '3.0 (key)']
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I am missing something, but what's wrong with simple:

```
>>> lst = ['3.0', '3.0 (key)', '2.0', '2.0 (key)', '1.0', '1.0 (key)', '1.1', '1.1 (key)']
>>> sorted(lst, reverse=True)
['3.0 (key)', '3.0', '2.0 (key)', '2.0', '1.1 (key)', '1.1', '1.0 (key)', '1.0']
```

EDIT: to address the OP problem: build new list, swap the last items if needed otherwise keep order, does not require to have pairs of values:

```
list_ = ['3.5 (key)',
         '3.0', '3.0 (key)',
         '2.5',
         '2.0', '2.0 (key)',
         '1.5 (key)',
         '1.0', '1.0 (key)',
         '1.1', '1.1 (key)',
         '0.9']

summary = []

for item in list_:
    summary.append(item)
    if 2 <= len(summary):
       if item.split()[0] == summary[-2]:
          summary.insert(-1, summary.pop(-1))

# summary
['3.5 (key)', 
 '3.0 (key)', '3.0', 
 '2.5', 
 '2.0 (key)', '2.0', 
 '1.5 (key)', 
 '1.0 (key)', '1.0', 
 '1.1 (key)', '1.1', 
 '0.9']
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: OK, as I suspected I did miss something.

Comment: @baduker : now it should be something that OP wants.